# Strange geometry appears after separating part of mesh

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to copy part of my mesh by selecting, duplicating it, then separating it. Every time I separate it I get that gray thing you see in the image.[image]

Comment: What are the modifiers added to the mesh ? This is the most common reason for this behaviour.

Comment: An armature, subsurf, particle system and a mask.

Comment: @MrZak You are right. I just identified the problem, it's the particle system. When I separate the mesh it becomes a mess. I tried disconnecting it first, separating, then reconnecting, and even though it looks much better than if I don't disconnect it, it does not look exactly the same as I had it before.

Comment: @MrZak Actually, nevermind, seems like that's another issue. When I open the file and render without modifying anything, the hair looks different than if I disconnect and reconnect it then render. So anyway, the answer to my original question is: disconnect particles, separate mesh, reconnect particles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this, I disconnected the particles, separated the mesh, then reconnected the particles.